# Flutter passing data between screens showing null data after passing

Tags: flutter

Hi i was experienced ionic developer but i am new to flutter i was trying to pass data between screens in flutter but when it navigates it shows null value , in debug mode before navigate there is values after navigate it shows null , here is my code please correct my code thanks.

Screen 1

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_field/date_field.dart';
import 'package:headletter/screens/Add_horoscope/marriage_info.dart';

class AddBasicInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddBasicInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddBasicInfoState createState() => _AddBasicInfoState();
}

class _AddBasicInfoState extends State<AddBasicInfo>{
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp()....
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
             final data1 = [
               {
                 "Name": inputName.text,
                 "Gender": _selectedGender,
                 "DOB":dobDate,
                 "DobTime":dobTime,
                 "Place": birthPlace.text,
                 "Landmark": landmark.text,
                 "birthNo": _selectedChild
               }
             ];
           
                  final String passingValue = "checking for passing";
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            MarriageInfo(passingValue: passingValue)),
                  );
                }
              }
          
            },
```

Screen 2

```
class MarriageInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  final String passingValue;
  const MarriageInfo({Key? key, required this.passingValue}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MarriageInfoState createState() => _MarriageInfoState();
}
```

Comment: You say: `after navigate it shows null`.  What is the "it"?  Can you perhaps supply the full code for `MarriageInfo` that tries to use `passingValue`?

Comment: @JonMountjoy i checked with breakpoints, u can see there is string is defined on the passing data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far now this is correct but while using `passingValue` on Screen2 you have to use `widget.passingValue`
e.g. `print(widget.passingValue);`

Answer (score 0):

you are using statefulwidget
You can describe constructor of statefullwidget like that

final String passingValue;

const MarriageInfo(this.number);

and than you can excess this value by

widget.passingValue

Answer (score 0):

You should use widget.passingValue instead of just that variable name.
The property is assigned to that widget, not to that state class.